# Ubuntu 16.04 Baldurs Gate Enhanced Edition Wont Start

Tags: drivers, 16.04, games

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and am trying to get Baldur's Gate Enhanced Edition running. I have the GOG version. I was able to get Civ 5 and Pillers of Eternity working no problem. When I run the game from the terminal this is what I get:

```
Running Baldur's Gate Enhanced Edition
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I have an R9 390. Would like some helping getting this running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is analogous to [a common Steam issue](/q/771032/175814).

To solve it you need to find `libstd++.so.6` in the installation directory of the game and rename it to something like `libstd++.so.6.orig` (or delete it altogether if you don't care about restoring it later without a re-installation of the game).

A possible command-line solution:

```
find /path/to/game -type f -name libstdc++.so.6 -exec mv -vT -- {} {}.orig \;
```